# Reshaping Dataframe in R

Tags: r, transpose

My data looks something like this:

```
ID  Updates
101 Open
101 Closed
102 Inactive
102 Open
```

I would like to create a dataset like below,

```
ID  Update1   Update2
101 Open      Closed
102 Inactive  Open
```

Can someone help me on getting this kind of table created in R

Comment: Please provide example data. What are `Value1` and `Value2` ?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dcast`.  Create a sequence column ('ind') by 'ID' and use `dcast` to reshape from 'long' to 'wide'.

```
library(reshape2)
df2 <- transform(df1, ind=paste0('Update', ave(seq_along(ID), ID,
                  FUN=seq_along)))
dcast(df2, ID~ind, value.var='Updates')
#   ID  Update1 Update2
#1 101     Open  Closed
#2 102 Inactive    Open
```

EDIT: If we already know that there will be only two elements per 'ID'

```
dcast(df1, ID~paste0('Update', 1:2), value.var='Updates')
#   ID  Update1 Update2
#1 101     Open  Closed
#2 102 Inactive    Open
```

Comment: Perfect solution. Worked for me.. Thanks @akrun